# Cannot move a camera on GMSMapView of Google Maps for iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps

I have created a GMSMapVIew objects as shown in code. Unfortunately, camera is not set on the right coordinates:

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:latitude
                                                        longitude:longitude
                                                             zoom:15];



mapView_ = [[GMSMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(505, 280, 427, 200)];
mapView_.camera = camera;
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;

UIViewController *mapController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
mapController.view = mapView_;

[self addChildViewController:mapController];
[self.view addSubview:mapView_];
```

I have tried additionally to relocate camera with following code, but with no success either:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D current = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude,longitude);
GMSCameraUpdate *currentCam = [GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:current];
[mapView_ animateWithCameraUpdate:currentCam];
```

Does anybody have an idea, what am I doing wrong, or is this simple a bug in Google Maps for iOS?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you using the same

```
    CLLocationCoordinate2D current = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude,longitude);

GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:latitude
                                                        longitude:longitude
                                                             zoom:15];
```

latitude and longitude? The obviously it wont work  as nothing changes ...

Comment: That was actually a second shot. It was same without it and camer apointed at one totally different location. I upgraded to last version and it seems it works now. Thanks for hint anyway!